# How to set a default user per repo in Git Extensions?

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

I have 2 projects and on each project I want different profiles to commit. But I would not like to change the git config every time I need to switch. How to do that?

Comment: Unless you are using the option `--global` `git config` will configure every repo individually

Comment: Now I see a "Local for current directory" at the top.

Comment: What do you mean with `at the top` ?

Comment: In the "Settings" -> "Git Config". I'm talking about the GUI app, Git Extensions and not the cli git.

Comment: OK, got it. And what is wrong with `Local for current directory`? Isn't this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

### From the GUI

- click on the **Tools > Settings** menu
- Select **Git Config**
- Tick the **Local for current repository** radio button
- Fill in your name and email
- Click **Apply**

[image]

### Using the command line

```
$ cd /path/to/your/local/project
$ git config user.name "Your name here"
$ git config user.email your.email@here.com
```

This will store the identity to be used for this project into its local `.git/config` file.